# Use a CSV cell value as a regex string using re in Python

Tags: python, regex

So I have a CSV document that has metadata, an XPATH and a Regex String in each row. The script uses the xpath to iterate over API requests and then I want to use the regex stored in the CSV with that xpath to search for something in the API results. My issue is how to use the data in a CSV row as a literal regex search string, like `r'^\w{2}.+'` versus a string to search against.

```
with open(rules, 'r+') as rulefile:
    rreader = csv.DictReader(rulefile)
    for row in rreader:
        for ip, apikey in keydict.iteritems():
            rulequery = {'type': 'config', 'action': 'get', 'key': apikey, 'xpath': row["xpath"]}
            rrule = requests.get('https://' + ip + '/api', params = rulequery, verify=False)
            rrex = re.compile('{}'.format(row["regex"]), re.MULTILINE)
            for line in rrule.text:
                config = rrex.findall(line)
                print(config)
```

Comment: What is the issue ? It doesn't work ? Do you get an error ?

Comment: No it just returns...                                                                                     []
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Answer (score 1):

So I think I may have found a solution, although Im not sure it is the best... Open for assistance if anyone has a better way to do it.

```
with open(rules, 'r+') as rulefile:
rreader = csv.DictReader(rulefile)
for row in rreader:
    for ip, apikey in keydict.iteritems():
        regex = row["regex"]
        rulequery = {'type': 'config', 'action': 'get', 'key': apikey, 'xpath': row["xpath"]}
        rrule = requests.get('https://' + ip + '/api', params = rulequery, verify=False)
        config = re.search(regex, rrule.text)
        print rrule.text[config.start():config.end()]
```